# Systematic vertex information about finite Young's lattice

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, lattice-orders, integer-partitions, analytic-combinatorics

Suppose that I have Young's lattice $Y_{\mu}$ (finite sublattice for everything included in $\mu$). See the red area in the linked picture I found online where $\mu=[22]$ and note that the arrows indicating inclusion are missing (should be going from left to right).

[$Y_{[22]}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/250CQ.png)

My question is simple: is there a way of systematically counting the number of 'incoming' edges for each vertex in the direction of inclusion? In the depicted case I would like to count the edges of every vertex (partition) inside the red area coming from left. Note that I'm not asking how to do it for a given partition -- that is easy. I'm interested in a systematic approach, for example, by a generating function. Actually, it could be a fine-grained rank-generating function which in this case is given by the $q$-binomial $\binom{4}{2}_q=1 + q + 2 q^2 + q^3 + q^4$. The answer to my question for $Y_{[22]}$ would be
$$\{0\},\{1\},\{\{1\},\{1\}\},\{2\},\{1\}$$
Zero incoming edge for $\varnothing$, one incoming edge for $\mu=[1]$ etc...

Comment: Some terminology: You're looking for the number of corners (or outer corners) of a partition.

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. So is there a way to know how many outer corners there are as I descend from the highest partition (that, is for all smaller partitions) but without going iteratively  ?

Comment: So with the input $[22]$ you want to generate the bivariate polynomial $1 + tq + 2tq^2 + t^2q^3 + tq^4$, or something more refined than that?  I can find things about generating functions for the number of corners of all partitions of $n$, say, but have not yet found anything combining number of corners with intervals in Young's lattice.  I would suggest that, after another few days, that you ask this on MathOverflow.